# Can I treat a local parameter variable as I would any other variable in method?

Tags: objective-c

Just want to be sure that I've got this right. Say I declare my own custom designated initialiser such as

`-(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data andImage:(UIImage *)image;`

Is it ok to then just do something like the following inside of it? :

```
self = [super init]; 
self.name = data[PLANET_NAME];
self.spaceImage = image;
return self;
```

and actually index into that parameter variable called 'data'? If so, why is it possible? Is a variable declared as a parameter indexable into just as an explicitly and separately declared dictionary variable would be? Also just as a side question, what is the best way to describe a 'parameter variable' - doesn't sound fully correct.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You asked if you can do what you are doing in your posted code. Did you try it? Did it work as you hoped?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and yes it worked.. I came here for verification, to dot off the 'i's. Every learner has a different method to learn and as I'm self-taught and not a genius I like to verify things sometimes even if I am 99% sure of it. This way just works for me and gets me there in the end. Thanks.

Comment: That's great. I'm not questioning the desire to learn and be sure. It just would have improved your question if you stated that you tried it, it worked, but you just had a question to be sure. Enjoy.

Comment: When I asked if it was 'ok to do something like that code' it was to give context to my question- I didn't mean it literally. Thanks if you meant well but I got that comment before back when I had about a score of 30 or something and it was a useful reminder. Now I always code, and verify if I think it adds breadth and here it really did because gnasher729 gave me a tip re checking for nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every parameter that is passed to a method turns into a local variable when the method is called. What would you do with a parameter if you couldn't use it? In addition, you can assign to a parameter, because it is not a const variable.

Note that you should always, always check that [super init] didn't return nil.